# Recursive Async/Await API call

Tags: c#, recursion, async-await

I have an async method that makes an API call to a vendor. The vendor has requested that in the event of an error, we make an additional 2 calls with exactly  the same information in the calls. My first thought for this scenario is to make my API method recursive. However, after looking at many questions on this site and other articles, I'm having a hard time grasping how async/await works with recursion.

My method (simplified for demonstration) follows. I'm not sure if I should be awaiting the recurisve call? Visual Studio throws the standard *Because this call is not awaited, execution will continue...etc* if I don't await the recursive call. It does appear to work when I do await the recursive call, I'm just afraid of what I'm doing to stack if I've done this incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int UserID, int Retry = 0)
{
     try 
     {
         var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myurlhere");
         //Set other request info like headers and payload


         var Response = await WebClient.SendAsync(Request);             
         return await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();         
     } 
     catch (Exception Ex)
     { 
          if (Retry <= 2)
          {
               Retry++;
               return await GetData(UserID, Retry); //Should I await this?
          }
          else 
          {
               return "";
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I would consider pushing the issue one level up the stack. Leave `GetData` as it was and build a `GetDataWithRetry` function that catches exceptions and retries up to X times. This was no recursion is necessary, and you have clear methods with clear names that indicate what they do.

Comment: Maybe consider [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)?

Comment: I am surprised that works.   Seem to me that result would come back to the catch block.

Comment: @paparazzo Why would that be a problem?

Comment: This isn't a recursive problem, it's a repetition problem. Recursion should be used where a problem can be solved by breaking it into smaller versions of the problem. That is not the case here. I would do something along the lines of @mjwills suggestion.

Comment: @Mike I would disagree only because the actual method is vastly more complex, and to have 2 of them that do the same thing would break the rules of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), at least IMO

Comment: That code does not even pass syntax.  Not all paths return a value.

Comment: @paparazzo You are correct, I left out a return when I was typing the question, oops! I do have a return in the real method. Edited question for clarity

Comment: @mituw16 Whether you separate out the retry logic from the rest of the business logic is independent of whether you use a recursive or iterative approach to implementing the retry logic.

Comment: @mituw16 Nobody was suggesting to have multiple copies of the code, just put a call to the single, complex part in a retry loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does appear to work when I do await the recursive call,

Grand, so.

> I'm just afraid of what I'm doing to stack if I've done this incorrectly.

Because `await`ing `Task`s that don't return synchronously is handled by a state machine, it is in fact less burden on the stack in such a case than if it was "normal" non-async code. The recursive call becomes another state machine and a reference to it is a field in the first state machine.

It's possible to take an iterative rather than recursive approach to this generally (have a loop and exit on first success) but really since even the non-async equivalent wouldn't have significant stack pressure there's no need to do things any differently than you have done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a situation where recursion is needed. As others have suggested I would use something like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetDataWithRetry(int UserID, int Tries = 1)
{
    Exception lastexception = null;

    for (int trycount=0; trycount < tries; trycount++)
        try
        {
            return await GetData(UserID);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            lastexception = Ex;
        }

    throw lastexception;
}

public async Task<string> GetData(int UserID)
{
     var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myurlhere");
     //Set other request info like headers and payload


     var Response = await WebClient.SendAsync(Request);             
     return await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing it out! I think I mis-understood what you and mjwills were suggesting.

Comment: You're wiping out the stack trace of the thrown exception, making it it much harder to debug.

Comment: @Servy This is not production-ready code. There are a few things wrong with it. It merely demonstrates the retry idea. That is why I said "something like".

Comment: @Mike And *the thing that you're trying to demonstrate* was something that you did wrong.  If you post code that has lots of things wrong with it then *people will end up doing those wrong things* because you told them that that was the solution.  If it was a problem with code not really relevant to the actual solution to the core problem, it'd be *less* of an issue, but even that isn't the case.

Comment: @Servy I think I got the retry idea across to the OP, but you have a point about it not being a complete solution. How would you answer this question?

Comment: To match the code in the question it should return an empty string on error. That is likely a bad idea, but either the iterative version here (I'd consider the general approach marginally better but not so much as to be worth refactoring) and the recursive in the question could be changed to `catch` with a filter so on the last attempt the `catch` doesn't catch at all and the exception is thrown with full stack trace.